# I want to generate different view or template for webapp into Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to have two templates in a webapp ?

Comment: "at once and different default". What does that actually mean?

Comment: different view generate by default.

Comment: why don't you create a new view from the two views ?

Comment: Have you ever heard of renderPartial?

Comment: who to create view then different view show

Comment: i don't know Have renderPartial !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `renderPartial()` instead of render in order to render multiple views.

```
$this->renderPartial('VIEW NAME',array('KEY'=>'VALUE'));
```

You can do this many times!

Yii also has other useful features in order to render multiple views, such as **decorators** and **clips**. I suggest you to take a look at the `decorators` and `clips` in `Yii`. These features are really cool!